# UISearchController with Parse objects?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to use a UISearchController to filter through an array of PFObjects.

```
var customers:[PFObjects] = [PFObjects]() //this is full of my objects.
var searchText:[PFObject] = [PFObjects]() //this has my searchTexts.
```

I have a column in my customers class called "searchText" that has all of my customers names, addresses and phone numbers. I am trying to figure out how to populate the search text array  then filter through the both of the arrays.
I have all my tableview delegates and data sources set up and the uisearchcontroller initialized.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {    

//How do i search through the array of searchTexts and the customers array?
}
```

I'm probably way off the mark for trying to filter through my pfobjects array...so any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to get a string entered in the search bar.

```
let textToSearch = searchController.searchBar.text
```

Then you need to search through `searchText` objects, if there's some, that match.

```
for searchObject in searchText{
    if searchObject.rangeOfString(textToSearch) != nil {
       //we found some object that contains text entered in search bar
       let foundIndex = find(searchText,searchObject)

       let foundCustomer = customers[foundIndex]
       // put found customer in filtered array and reload the table view.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey bud, is searchObject supposed to be my array of Searchtexts from my parse class? I can't get searchObject.rangeOfString to work.

Comment: Yes, searchObject is from your Parse objects array, I don't know what fields it has, so you need to get string from it and then do `rangeOfString`